# How do you disable the admin panel Inbox Notification pop up?

Tags: admin-panel

We've all had this at one point or another, I've looked around and cannot find anything obvious.

**How can you disable the pop up window that is displayed when you login to the admin panel when there are new messages?**

Note: I do not want to disable the message feature completely, I just don't want to have the pop-up appear when I login.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question? I am talking about your _**Note: I do not want to disable the message feature completely, I just don't want to have the pop-up appear when I login.**_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1

Under:

> System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Modules Output
>   simply set Mage_AdminNotification to “Disable”.

Method 2

The previous method works fine but potentially, a user can re-enable these easily. To make the change a bit more difficult to undo, we can disable the module from the modules XML files. If we already have a custom module, we can simply add:

```
<Mage_AdminNotification>
    <active>false</active>
</Mage_AdminNotification>
```

To our module XML file. A complete example could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageBase_Custom>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
                <Mage_Cms />
            </depends>
        </MageBase_Custom>
        <Mage_AdminNotification>
                <active>false</active>
        </Mage_AdminNotification>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Reference [LINK](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-disable-admin-notifications-in-the-magento-back-end/)

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.nyssasutherland.com/how-to-disable-annoying-magento-admin-popup-messages/

Simply login, go to System -> Configuration -> Advanced and change the “Mage_AdminNotification” drop down to disabled.

Comment: Does it disable the inbox feature?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to disable the message feature completely, You should not disable `Mage_AdminNotification`.

To just disable the annoying popup you should rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Window`. File path is `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Window.php`. You should override `canShow()` function like this:

```
class Your_Module_Block_Notification_Window extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Window
{
    public function canShow()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) you can find more on overriding in magento.